# Vaadin 6 to 7 migration - UI provider error

Tags: migration, vaadin, vaadin7

I am migrating from Vaadin 6 to Vaadin 7.
After deploying to jBoss 7.1.1, I can open the page, but there comes an error:
[image: The error on the index page]

Does anyone know what that means in general and how I could possibly solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you migrate? There is this wiki entry availble https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Migrating+from+Vaadin+6+to+Vaadin+7

Comment: I did it this way, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: Which code?
There are about 40000 files in the project

Comment: please don't use screenshots for error messages

Comment: Since UI class is causing the issue, web.xml (if you're using one) and UI class codes should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

In your web.xml file you need to provide UI init param, which should be fully qualified class name of your UI class.

Example:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>UI</param-name>
        <param-value>my.package.MyUI</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Alternatively, you can have your custom UI provider:

```
<servlet> 
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class> 
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>UIProvider</param-name> 
        <param-value>my.package.MyUIProvider</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
</servlet>
```

More about implementing custom UI providers [here](http://www.vinceller.de/?q=node/14).

Comment: Thanks. What exactly do you mean by UI class?
There is a class for the index page and another class for the main page

Comment: https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html In Vaadin 6 there used to be Application class which is now in Vaadin 7 UI class. It is described right at the beginning of the Vaadin 6 to 7 migration guide.

Comment: I know that already.
But which one of the two above mentioned classes should I write into the web.xml file?

Comment: If these are two views in one UI then add just one UI. If both of those are UI classes (extends UI) then you need to declare both in your web.xml - use twice the snippet I provided in the first example.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that and be back later